# Foundation 6 grid columns are always 100% width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm currently working on a project for which I use foundation 6.
I have this weird problem that my columns stack vertically (they're all 100% width of the screen)

the very simply code that I use is this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="small-4 large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="small-6 large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>
```

this is copied directly from the basic grid examples on the foundation website. I'm certain that i've linked to the stylesheet correctly, because even when I use the full path of the stylesheets this keeps happening.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You should inspect your div in chrome's inspector et check which css rule applies last on your divs. I believe one of your custom css rules overrides the foundation's ones.

Comment: @PierreBurton thanks for the tip, but app.css is still empty so that unfortunately didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the newest version of Foundation comes with their XY Grid enabled and it wont call the CSS of the class "small-2 large-4 columns"!

If you're using SASS just set the arguments to false in the includes, but I assume you're just using CSS so if you just re-download a custom version and then just check 'float grid' it will get you back to the older grid system and your code should work!

[image]

If you want to learn more about the new XY Grid heres a link: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html

And heres a link to download the custom foundation version:
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, this fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because my rep is under 50, but I wanted to say I am also having this issue. Downloaded Foundation 6 from the site, I have all the files, and I haven't touched the app.css file. Here is my code
Both columns at 100% width.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class ="row " style= "background-color: aqua">
      <div class = "small-6 large-6 columns" style= "background-color: lightblue">content</div>
      <div class = "small-6 large-6 columns">more content</div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```